# Problemas com Json

Tags: php, json

Eu tenho um ficheiro com pedidos em formato JSON feitos a um servidor e o meu problema é que saber como é que posso pegar nesses pedidos ou seja nessas linhas e tratar no php

Exemplo de como esta o Ficheiro

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Ou seja cada linha é a resposta dada ao pedido que faço.

Alguem sabe como posso fazer isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Li a resposta anterior do @rray e apesar de certa na manipulação JSON, penso que não responde à pergunta na totalidade. A melhor resposta e de acordo com a pergunta: ler de um "ficheiro texto formatado em json" a solução é:

```
$handle = fopen("ficheiro.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $arr = json_decode($line, true);

        // se a linha lida resultar num JSON então temos um array
        if (is_array($arr)) {

            // Neste momento já tem os campos no array $arr
            // o código seguinte é apenas para mostrar o resultado
            // pelo que pode ser removido e substituido pela lógica desejada
            foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
                echo "{$k}={$v} ";
            }
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "error ao abrir o ficheiro bla bla bla";
}
```

Nota: é importante dizer e de acordo com a pergunta como o ficheiro é produzido com resultados de um serviço externo é importante validar com `isset` o nome dos campos pois algum poderá não estar presente por algum motivo e em consequência gerar erros indesejados na sua manipulação.

Answer (score 3):

Para transforma uma json em um array, use a função [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), depois faça um foreach e chame as chaves que desejar.

```
$original = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

/*para pegar o ficheiro basta utilizar:*/
//$original = file_get_contents('ficheiro.json");
/* transforma em um json válido */
/* str_replace irá trocar '}' por '},' adicionando as vírgulas */
/* rtrim vai remover a última vírgula */
$json = '[' . rtrim(str_replace('}', '},', $original), ',') . ']';    

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($arr as $item){
    echo $item['a'] . ' - ' .$item['b'] .' - '.$item['c'] .' - '.$item['d'] .' - '.$item['e'] .' - '. '<br>';
}
```

### [Ideone Exemplo](https://ideone.com/aTiKYB)

Comment: o problema e que o ficheiro que esta a ser criado nao e controlado por mim e no final não tem a virgula

Comment: @TesterApo Atualizei a resposta do `rray` com uma alternativa pra você

Comment: Obrigado pela edição @MaiconCarraro :D